# C++ 11 threading API: is there a free implementation for MSVC 2010?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, c++11

Is there any free 3rd-party implementation of std::thread API for use in MSVC versions older than 11?

Comment: I'd guess the closest you'd get is boost::thread but curious to see other answers.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Never used boost::thread, nor did I know it's somewhat similar to std::thread. What a nice occasion to start learning boost :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost::thread  is a way to go!

Answer (score 1):

My [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk) library provides a complete implementation of the C++11 thread library for MSVC 2005, 2008 and 2010, including `std::thread` and `std::async`, but it's not free. For a free implementation the closest you can get with MSVC is boost, but there are a few differences.

Comment: Yes, I know about just::thread, but I only need some std-similar library till my issue with installing VS 11 DP is resolved, so I definitely want a free library.